# JSON-RPC: TheDao contract returning not null values for not existing methods in the contract

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, json-rpc, the-dao

When using the geth JSON-RPC `eth_call` to retrieve some ERC20 token contracts `symbol` and `name` information, it comes up the case of TheDao contract.
I was expecting to receive a null/empty string like `0x` in response to calling the non-existing methods in any contract when using `eth_call`. But for TheDAO I have noticed I'm getting a 32 bytes word `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`.

Is it a right assumption to expect a null/empty word when querying non existing methods for any contract? Do other contract returns not empty words for non-existing methods too?

P.S.: this is a call against my local geth node to retrieve `name` information for TheDAO:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to": "0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413", "data":"0x06fdde03"}, "latest"],"id":<id>}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://geth.local.node:8545
```

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke a function that doesn't exists in a contract it will call the fallback function.

In the case of the DAO it will execute the following function which returns a bool.

```
function () returns (bool success) {
    if (now < closingTime + creationGracePeriod && msg.sender != address(extraBalance))
        return createTokenProxy(msg.sender);
    else
        return receiveEther();
}
```